# Accessing elements inside a returned sequelize object

Tags: discord.js, sequelize.js

In my `messageReactionAdd.js` file I'm trying to just get the value of one of the properties in the returned object from my query.  How can I pull the value `myDiscordUsername` from the returned query object?

### /utils/database.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const   sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'user', 'password', {
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    host: 'localhost',
    storage: 'database.sqlite',
    logging: false,
    transactionType: 'IMMEDIATE',
});

module.exports = sequelize;
```

### /models/game_user.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../utils/database');

const GameSession = sequelize.define(
    'game_user', {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.BIGINT(20),
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
        },
        discordId: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
        },
    },
    {
        initialAutoIncrement: 1000,
    },
);

module.exports = GameSession;
```

### /events/messageReactionAdd.js

```
const { Events } = require('discord.js');
const GameUsers = require('../models/game_user');

module.exports = {
    name: Events.MessageReactionAdd,
    async execute(reaction, user) {
        if (user.bot) {
            return;
        }

        // Get the current user's id
        let userId = null;
        const user_current = await GameUsers.findOrCreate(
            {
                where: {
                    discordId: user.username,
                },
            },
        )
            .then((gameUser) => {
                console.log(gameUser);
                // console.log(userId);
            });
    },
};
```

### RETURNED OBJECT

```
[
  game_user {
    dataValues: {
      id: 1,
      discordId: 'myDiscordUsername',
      createdAt: 2024-02-05T23:59:13.235Z,
      updatedAt: 2024-02-05T23:59:13.235Z
    },
    _previousDataValues: {
      id: 1,
      discordId: 'myDiscordUsername',
      createdAt: 2024-02-05T23:59:13.235Z,
      updatedAt: 2024-02-05T23:59:13.235Z
    },
    uniqno: 1,
    _changed: Set(0) {},
    _options: {
      isNewRecord: false,
      _schema: null,
      _schemaDelimiter: '',
      raw: true,
      attributes: [Array]
    },
    isNewRecord: false
  },
  false
]
```